# Datagridview C# Column with Date error format when exporting to excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, datagridview

I have a problem when I try to export a `datagridview` to an Excel file, the date column that I have, is this:

[image]

But when I'm exporting to Excel, the format is changed, or is a string.

[image]

I set the format:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[3].ValueType = typeof(DateTime);
dataGridView1.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/mm/yyyy";
```

This is my code for export:

```
public void ExportarDataGridViewExcel(DataGridView grd)
{
    try
    {

        SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
        fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
        fichero.FileName = "ReporteExportado";
        if (fichero.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;


            aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
            hoja_trabajo =
                (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

            //Recorremos el DataGridView rellenando la hoja de trabajo
            for (int i = 0; i < grd.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < grd.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    if ((grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null) == false)
                    {

                        hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = grd.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();

                        label3.Text = "Registros: " + i + " de "+dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
                        prgBar.Minimum = 0;
                        prgBar.Maximum = 100;
                        int valor;
                        valor = (100 * i) / dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
                        prgBar.Value = valor;

                    }
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Tarea realizada");
            label3.Text = "";
            prgBar.Value = 0;
            libros_trabajo.SaveAs(fichero.FileName,
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
            libros_trabajo.Close(true);
            aplicacion.Quit();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error al exportar la informacion debido a: " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I see some questions, I found that is a Excel problem, or some also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
hoja_trabajo.Columns[4].NumberFormat = "dd/mm/aaaa";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I fixed it by typing the column by a DateTime type : `dataTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));` (before it was a string type)

In Rows, I put the DateTime value from my data :
`dt.Rows.Add(data.Date)` (before it was a .ToShortDateString() value)

In my export method, I don't specify any type or number format : `worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j] = dgvTaches.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value;`

Hope that can helps in future.